# Installing libLAS on docker python - No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, liblas

I'm working in python in docker, and I need to add the package libLAS.

I usually just add a simple line to my dockerfile, for libLAS it would is:

```
Run pip install liblas
```

Docker seems to be able to build the image, but when I run a python script with the line:

```
import liblas
```

it gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    import liblas
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/liblas/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .core import get_version
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/liblas/core.py", line 158, in <module>
    las = ctypes.CDLL(lib_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: liblas_c.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I don't know what this error message means. Can someone please tell me how I can use liblas in python on docker?

Comment: Could do you add your dockerfile please?

Comment: You could install C++ version of liblas inside docker by following command:
apt-get update
&& apt-get install liblas3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `RUN apt-get -y install liblas-c3` in your `Dockerfile` and then `Docker build .` to install it.

Comment: This works perfectly!
I made this the accepted answer because -y is needed so it doesn't abort because it needs more space.

Comment: Where did you get this command? Is there somewhere to look it up or something? I need to install pdal now, and I keep running into this problem...

Answer (score 0):

You are just installing the python bindings. You need also to install liblas itself. If you are using Ubuntu/Debian, try

```
$ apt-get install liblas-c3
```